# Rest API call in Android using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, postman, retrofit

i want to build a GPS Android App with Rest APIs requests using Retrofit. However, I have a problem with a requets. The `response.body()` is null. All of my other requests work fine. I hope someone can help me ...

[image: request Class]
[image: Error Code]
[image: Postman]

Answer (score 1):

Exception is saying that `response.body()` returns null. You can set breakpoint on this line and check if it is null or not.